# Creating and uploading JSON by user is not a standard practice? or it is confusing to user?

Tags: usability, standards

Scenario : User will get an excel file and will enter data in the excel file. Once the user is done with filling data, the user will click on the button that will validate and create JSON file out of the excel file. Once the JSON file is created at user end then the user just has to upload the JSON into system.

The above scenario confuses user with uploading JSON or it is not a standard practice in UX?

Comment: It seems like what's confusing isn't that you're asking users to upload JSON, but rather that you're providing them with a conversion tool and an upload tool *separately* when you could just combine the two functions. It's kind of like visiting a store in another country, handing your currency to the clerk, receiving the equivalent local currency back, then immediately returning it to the clerk to pay for your purchases. Why doesn't he just keep it, and save you the trouble of handing it back to him?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of audience you are targeting, but regardless it's not a pleasant user experience.

There are still some confusions about your questions as well like: "User will click on a button that will validate and create JSON file out of excel file" - where will user create that JSON file? in excel itself? or he will have to upload the file somewhere to validate?

Depending on the case -

If you're doing validation online (user have to upload the excel file) then it doesn't make any sense to download and re-upload the JSON file - it should be done online only.

If it needs to be done in excel, providing right guidelines for creating excel sheet, validating it and converting it into excel will be required.

Again, everything depends on your target user audience: If it's a small audience which will be willing to go through the process then it's okay (EVERYTHING IS IN THAT CASE)

Have you considered creating an excel plugin which will do it all for users. If the audience is large enough - this can provide the best possible user experience.

Please edit the question and add more details about the problem, maybe then the community will be able to provide better guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on who the user is.

If it's for a countable trained users then it's ok, but if you are asking about all types of users who use web then it's not a good user experience. The system should do most of the work and ask users to do very little.

In your case the system should accept excel file, convert it into JSON and store by itself.